# Import existing class diagram into modeling project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

I got a class diagram created with VS 2010 whose modeling project got lost somehow. So I am left with the foo.classdiagram and foo.classdiagram.layout files. When I try to open it in another modeling project, I just get a blank class diagram.

Is theres any way to import existing class diagrams into a modeling project? If not, does anyone know of another tool that's able to open VS .classdiagram files?

Answer (score 1):

The standard interchange format for UML is XMI. This only ever works so-so as the file format only includes model elements and connectors, not the visual diagram layouts. It might still be worth a shot, though.

Visual Studio does not include XMI export functionality out of the box, but I found a reference to an extension [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Adding-a-menu-item-to-UML-d307bdbd). The download link for the version for VS 2010 is dead, but perhaps you can run it the 2012 version instead.

Finally, if you have the source code for the classes you can always reverse-engineer them into UML (depending on what modelling tool you use). Sparx Systems' Enterprise Architect can even reverse-engineer certain binaries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it did not help me to solve the problem and I am giving up now. Your reference to XMI actually brought me a little further, but the extension you mentioned as well as one that comes with VS 2010 Feature Pack 2 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657797%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) only support XMI 2.1, whereas my files are formatted in XMI 1.0.